# How to remove all symbols and spaces from the String?

Tags: python, function, csv

I am reading a csv file through `csv.reader()`, I want to read the values free from every kind of symbol or space and in lower-case Like:

```
a = " Kingston-(USB) = 1GB, 2GB, 32GB . . . "
```

convert 'a' like this:

```
a = "kingstonusb1gb2gb32gb"
```

I just want alphabets and numbers in my data.
Symbol of any kind should be removed.
I have used `.lower()` function and `.strip()` function to do this. but strip function just removes spaces between words, whereas I want to remove every kind of symbol.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = " Kingston-(USB) = 1GB, 2GB, 32GB . . . "
>>> re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9]', '', a.lower())
'kingstonusb1gb2gb32gb'
```

Or a generator:

```
>>> import string
>>> allowed = string.lowercase + string.digits
>>> ''.join(c for c in a.lower() if c in allowed)
'kingstonusb1gb2gb32gb'
```

Or something fast:

```
>>> import string
>>> allowed = set(string.lowercase + string.digits)
>>> ''.join(filter(allowed.__contains__, a.lower()))
'kingstonusb1gb2gb32gb'
```

Comment: I beat you to the generator -- and mine operates in O(N) rather than O(N^2) ;-)

Comment: @mgilson and Blender, I beat you both :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ascii, you can use str.translate to remove everything sans digits and alpha from your lower case string

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters, digits
>>> ascii = set(chr(e) for e in range(128))
>>> ascii_sans_alpha = ''.join(ascii.difference(ascii_letters + digits))
>>> a = " Kingston-(USB) = 1GB, 2GB, 32GB . . . "
>>> a.lower().translate(None,ascii_sans_alpha)
'kingstonusb1gb2gb32gb'
```

And how fast is this? Use the timeit reference

```
>>> def mgilson(a, good = set(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)):
    return ''.join(x for x in a.lower() if x in good)

>>> def blender_re(a):
    return re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9]', '', a.lower())

>>> def blender_gen(a, allowed = string.lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(c for c in a.lower() if c in allowed)

>>> def blender_fast(a, allowed = set(string.lowercase + string.digits)):
    return ''.join(filter(allowed.__contains__, a.lower()))

>>> def abhijit(a, ascii_sans_alpha = ''.join(set(chr(e) for e in range(128)).difference(ascii_letters + digits))):
    return a.lower().translate(None,ascii_sans_alpha)

>>> time_dict = {"abhijit": "from __main__ import string, a",
             "blender_re":"from __main__ import re, a, abhijit",
             "blender_gen": "from __main__ import string, a",
             "blender_fast": "from __main__ import string, a",
             "mgilson": "from __main__ import string, a"}
>>> for k, v in time_dict.items():
    t = timeit.Timer(stmt="{}(a)".format(k),setup = "{},{}".format(v,k))
    print "Timing for {} is {}".format(k, t.timeit(100000))


Timing for blender_fast is 0.573348026237
Timing for blender_re is 0.632169556846
Timing for blender_gen is 0.720916486331
Timing for mgilson is 0.586592185393
Timing for abhijit is 0.203489867547
>>>
```

Comment: I thought about `translate` ... but it seemed messy so I didn't bother.  I'm glad you did.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do something like:

```
import string
good = set(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)
a = ''.join(x for x in a.lower() if x in good)
```

It's probably not the most efficient, but it should work and it's pretty easy to read/understand.

Comment: +1 Is there any difference between `ascii_lowercase` and `string.lowercase`?

Comment: @Blender -- `ascii_lowercase` isn't locale dependent.